# Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis select different database than db0

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, redis

a question on understanding which redis database is used and how it can be configured.

i have a default *ASP.NET Core Web Application* and a default configured local *redis-server* (containing 15 databases)

[image]

Over Package Management Console i have installed:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis
```

Redis is configured in *Startup.cs* like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
    {
        option.Configuration = "127.0.0.1";
        option.InstanceName = "master";
    });
}
```

The code to read and write values into the cache is taken from the docs:

```
var cacheKey = "TheTime";
var existingTime = _distributedCache.GetString(cacheKey);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingTime))
{
    return "Fetched from cache : " + existingTime;
}
else
{
    existingTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
    _distributedCache.SetString(cacheKey, existingTime);
    return "Added to cache : " + existingTime;
}
```

But this code only uses the default database *db0* no matter what i configure.

E.g. using this configuration:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
{
    option.Configuration = "127.0.0.1";
    option.InstanceName = "db6";
});
```

leads to:

[image]

**What do i have to configure to use e.g. db6?**

Do i have to use *Stackexchange.Redis* for this?

Comment: You can read https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html. You are interested in "DefaultDatabase" option I suppose.

Comment: can you provide a link to docs? for what you said in question here: `The code to read and write values into the cache is taken from the docs`

Comment: I want to use Redis cache in my project. Do you prefer to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis` or `StackExchange.Redis`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis is [using](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis/RedisCache.cs#L9) Stackexchange.Redis to [connect](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis/RedisCache.cs#L177) to Redis.

The `Configuration` string is [documented on StackExchange.Redis](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html). That said, you should be able to do:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
{
    option.Configuration = "127.0.0.1;defaultDatabase=4";
    option.InstanceName = "master";
});
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but how do i connect to multiple database with one configuration? is it even possible?

Comment: @GuoHuang Did you find solution for multiple database with one connection?

Comment: Looking for a way to work with different databases using `IDistributedCache` too.